# Disable Windows Update in Windows 10 IoT Enterprise

Tags: windows, group-policy, automatic-update

I am setting up touch-based systems for use in the construction industry out in the field. Many of the systems have access to mobile networks through a modem, but I do not want to use this limited capacity for Windows Updates.

The system has two Windows user accounts. One is used by the user, the other is an admin account where I have configured the Local Group Policy on all of them [as described here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328010/how-to-configure-automatic-updates-by-using-group-policy-or-registry-s)

Despite this, the systems occasinally decide to download updates without any requests and install them upon user reboot. This is not a good thing. Any suggestions as to what I might be missing? Is there another setting, or might some updates be lying dormant in my system image and then pop up within a couple of days?

Comment: Disable the Windows Update service in Services.

Comment: The simplest way to avoid this issue is to implement your own WSUS solution.  However, if you don't have a configuration that prevents users from doing whatever they want (like installing updates), you might not have the infrastructure to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable AutoUpdate on Windows 10 (and Server 2016+) by importing this Registry file (or manually editing with RegEdit):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000001
```